# Build bidimensional table based on many-to-many EF relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to build a bi-dimensional table based on a Driver/Race/Points relationships.

Models:

```
public class Race
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime RaceStart { get; set; }
    public Circuit Circuit { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DriverRacePoint> DriverRacePoints { get; set; }
}

public class Driver
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Standing { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DriverRacePoint> DriverRacePoints { get; set; }
}

public class DriverRacePoint
{
    [Key, Column("Driver_Id", Order = 0)]
    public int Driver_Id { get; set; }

    [Key, Column("Race_Id", Order = 1)]
    public int Race_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Driver_Id")]
    public virtual Driver Driver { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Race_Id")]
    public virtual Race Race { get; set; }

    public string Points { get; set; }
}
```

The result view:

```
        |   Race1   |   Race2   |   Race3   |   Race4  |
Driver1 |  points   |   points  |   points  |  points   | total points
Driver2 |  points   |   points  |   points  |  points   | total points  
Driver3 |  points   |   points  |   points  |  points   | total points
```

The lines order is not by the total but by the `Driver.Standing`

How do I build the ViewModel from the `DbContext` to get the result view?

Here is an example of the result I need:

http://en.espnf1.com/f1/motorsport/season/138549.html?template=standings

Comment: Do you have a collection of objects to start with ? Or do you want to create the result view for all drivers in the database?

Comment: Hi thanks. I want to create the list for all the races of a specified year, and include all the drivers that have made point in that race. Here is an example: http://en.espnf1.com/f1/motorsport/season/138549.html?template=standings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why the `Points` property in the `DriverRacePoint` entity is `string`, but if you change that property for a numeric type, for example `int`, you could do this to obtain the info that you need:

```
 using (var db = new YourDbContext())
 {
   var query = (from driver in db.Drivers
                join drp in db.DriverRacePoints on driver.Id equals drp.Driver_Id
                join race in db.Races on drp.Race_Id equals race.Id
                where race.RaceStart.Year==2014 //races for an specific year
                group new {driver,drp, race} by driver.Id into g
                select new {DriverId=g.Key,// The driver Id
                            RacesWithPoints=g.Select(a=>new {a.race,a.drp.Points}),// All the races ( and the points X race) where the driver participates
                            TotalPoints=g.Sum(a=>a.drp.Points)// Total of points
                           }).OrderByDescending(e=>e.TotalPoints);
   //use the data that you get from this query
 }
```

---

### Update 1

If you need the driver info then you can modify the query this way:

```
    var query = (from driver in db.Drivers
                join drp in db.DriverRacePoints on driver.Id equals drp.Driver_Id
                join race in db.Races on drp.Race_Id equals race.Id
                where race.RaceStart.Year==2014 //races for an specific year
                group new {driver,drp, race} by driver.Id into g
                select new {    DriverName = g.FirstOrDefault().driver.Name,
                                DriverUrlSlug = g.FirstOrDefault().driver.UrlSlug,
                                // All the races ( and the points X race) where the driver participates
                                RacesWithPoints = g.Select(a => new StandingRacePointsVM { RacePoints = a.drp.Points == null ? -1 : a.drp.Points }).ToList(),
                                TotalPoints = g.Sum(a => a.drp.Points),
                                Standing = g.FirstOrDefault().driver.Standing
                            }).OrderBy(d => d.Standing).ToList();
```

> For the list of races in the header, how do suggest that I build it?

Well, the problem is you don't know if some driver was involved in all the races. So I think you need to do another query for that:

```
  var query2 = from race in db.Races
                where race.RaceStart.Year == 2014
                select new {race.Id, race.Name};
```

---

### Update 2

I think this query is better for you but I can't test it because I don't have your model and data. This query will get you all the drivers, and for each driver you will get the list of all the races, including where he was not involved:

```
  var query3 = (from driver in db.Drivers
                join drp in db.DriverRacePoints on driver.Id equals drp.Driver_Id
                from race in db.Races
                where race.RaceStart.Year == 2014
                select new {  driver,drp, race })
               .GroupBy(e => e.driver.Id)
               .Select(g => new
                {
                    DriverName = g.FirstOrDefault().driver.Name,
                    RacesWithPoints = g.Select(a => new { a.race.Name, Points = a.drp.Race_Id == a.race.Id ? 0 : a.drp.Points }), // All the races (if the driver  was involved => you have the Points value, otherwise, the value is 0 )
                    TotalPoints = g.Sum(a => a.drp.Points)// Total of points
                }).OrderByDescending(e=>e.TotalPoints);
```

Now to create the header, you can choose the first driver an iterate foreach race using the `Name`.

Comment: Hi thanks! I use string for Points because I can get races with decimal points like 10.5 and I am still learning the best way to manipulate and store the data in Sql-Server, any sugestion for that? To build the View, I present the Driver's Name (how?), the list of RacesWithPoints array (with a foreach?) and the total Points, correct? For the list of races in the header, how do suggest that I build it? The result must look like this: http://en.espnf1.com/f1/motorsport/season/138549.html?template=standings

Comment: I think you could use the [decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/364x0z75.aspx) type for that field

Comment: Thanks! If a driver don't participate in a Race, it get's the "--" string in the table view has the example I have shared, to indicated that he did not finish or did not participate in the race.

Comment: @Patrick, check the update 2, I think that query is better for you purpose

Comment: Hi, I was able to put up and running the 1 solution of yours but how can I order it by driver's standing?

Comment: Hello @Patrick, I updated all the methods to order by `TotalPoints`

Comment: Hi, the order is defined by the property public int Standing { get; set; } of the Driver

Comment: I did not imagine you was referring to that property;), check the update 1

Comment: Hi, in the line ".OrderByDescending(e=>e.Driver.Standing);" I don't have access to the Driver.Standing. After "e." it don't appears the ".Driver" entity to access the Standing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72955/discussion-between-octavioccl-and-patrick).

Comment: Hello @Patrick, If you think my answer helped you to solve your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hi, of course! Sorry about the delay. I had to include the Standing in the Select so I can show it in the table before the driver's name and I use it to order the result, so I will check your answer but I will put the final solution or you want to update your answer?

Comment: No problem ;),  I'm going to update the "Update 1" with the solution you wanted

Comment: Thank you once again! The solution I used is the Update 1 available here: http://www.f1flash.com/classificacoes/

Comment: Hi! I found a problem with the query. Please check the table http://www.f1flash.com/Classificacoes/ it's not ordering the RacesWithPoints by Race_Id. Can you help me on that?

Comment: Which of the three queries are you using? I checked your website but I didn't see any issue. Could you be more specific?

Comment: I am using Update 1. The issue is that for example you have Lewis Hamilton and Nico Rosberg with 25 points in the first race and it's not correct, I have 25 for Lewis (who won the race) and 18 for Nico.

Comment: But I don't think that is not caused by the query, you should check your data in the `DriverRacePoints` table on your DB. There is where you are going to find that both racers have the same amount of points for that race.

Comment: I have double check and I have driver_Id:8 (Lewis), race_Id: 22 (Australia), Points: 25 and driver_Id: 15 (Nico), race_Id: 22 and Points: 18,00

Comment: Ok, I think I found your issue, you need to order `RacesWithPoints` list by `race_Id`: `RacesWithPoints = g.OrderBy(a=>a.race.Id).Select(a => new StandingRacePointsVM { RacePoints = a.drp.Points == null ? -1 : a.drp.Points }).ToList()`. I'm guessing you are showing the races ordered by raceId too.

Comment: Great! Problem solved: http://www.f1flash.com/Classificacoes/ I had tried to order in that place but I was not getting any suggestion from the editor so I thought that I could not do that :S. Thank you again for your help and I wish you a great 2016!